# Transferring data with $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, data-transfer

I'm completely confused with the `data` transferred by a `jQuery-AJAX` (specifically I've been using `$.post` mostly)

I've had a few attempts at transferring data to/from a PHP page and I'm left unsure what to use when, and how.

I've seen it done in a bunch of ways:

```
var dataString = 'username='+ username + '&userpassword=' + password;   

var dataString = '<?php echo $someVariable ?>';
```

I've seen it done with `serialize()`, `json_encode`, `stringify`, sometimes nothing at all. I find this very confusing, how do I know which to use, when and how? And most importantly, what tutorial/guide can I read to understand this thoroughly?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between PHP and Javascript.

Comment: PHP runs on the server. JS runs on the client. Read through all of MDN's tutorials/developer documentation then some

Comment: I appreciate the constructive comments, but I can't see any connection between that and what I've asked.

Comment: That's because you don't understand the difference between PHP and Javascript or client and server.

Comment: `json_encode` is a PHP function; the rest of your question is client-side.

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
$.post(url, {
    username: ...,
    password: ...
});
```

and then in your PHP the fields will appears as `$_POST['username']`, etc.

The only time this ever gets more complicated is if you wish to send multiple values for the same key (which isn't standardised in the `x-www-url-formencoded` syntax) or if the values you want to send are themselves objects or arrays of values.  In the latter case, it would make sense to convert the *values* (but not the entire form data) to JSON, and decode them in your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url:url,
            dataType: 'json',
            type:'POST',
            data:{username:youusernamevalue,password:yourpasswordvalue}, 
            success:function(data){
                //do something
            },
            error:function(){
             do something 
            }
        });
```